# how do I create a client in django?

Tags: python, django, tcpserver

I am working on a web application that use Python => (server) and Django => (client):
I would like to know how to make (write) a client for Django; example: when i want to display a list I must send a request to the server and then display it on my web page. do you have any ideas to make that?? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) goes over templates.

Further, if you are trying to retrieve data without loading the page, AJAX is what you are looking for.  [Here are some AJAX references for Django.](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX)

Let us know if you have a *specific* question about a Django page.

Comment: Thank you abalos for the links i'm gonna test it with ajax (that seems to do what i wanted)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get Django, while processing a view, to make an HTTP request to another server, you'll need to use either [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) on Python 2 or [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/http.client.html) on Python 3.

Comment: many people prefer the third party Requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: I Found a solution with omnibus python library. Here is the link for the doc: http://django-omnibus.readthedocs.org/ .
It is a websocket that make web client and python server communicating with each other. thank you for your help !!